# Why won't this dimension roll up?

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

The picture indicates a scenario, "A", where dimensions of shirt size (S,M,L,XL) on rows are correctly pivoted against colors Blue and Red.

But, in a production environment, I am encountering scenario B where the row dimension doesn't roll up and, instead, is repeated in a separate group for each column.

I actually cannot reproduce scenario B using test data so I'm at a loss as to what would cause this to occur in the first place. The image shown of scenario B is a mockup.

I've ruled-out blanks and non-numeric types. In fact, even with blanks and non-numeric types I can't force scenario B to occur in a controlled setting. I've also ruled out differences in the dimension names, e.g. trailing or leading spaces. (At one point, I exported the data using Power BI to a csv--then created a new Power BI workbook and imported the data. Couldn't repro the problem.)

Platforms involved are Power BI desktop connected to an Analysis Services Tabular model.

UPDATE: Although I initially perceived this as a data modeling issue, it occurs to me that the fact that the underlying data platform is Azure Cosmos Db, and that the AAS connector for Cosmos was still in Beta at the time the model was initially created, that this could indeed be related to a platform bug or some model corruption and has nothing to do with the data model.

Comment: Check if values in Level2 are trimmed. Spaces can make them different

Comment: I've updated the question to mention that this, too, has been ruled out. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: If you put just the sizes column in a table visual, do you get 4 or 8 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this result if there is a level that corresponds to the color. For example,

[image: Hierarchy]

where `Blue = 1` and `Red = 2` when comparing `Color` and `Level1`.

I'm not sure exactly where the issue is, but I'd guess that there is something creating a hidden hierarchy if your sizes are indeed identical for both colors.

Comment: You're probably onto something, but I still can't figure it out. There is a hierarchy defined in the model, but it wasn't being used--the dimension attributes were added independent of the hierarchy. Nevertheless I completely deleted the hierarchy as a test but it hasn't made any difference. Also interesting is that querying with DAX studio does not produce these results, neither a pivot table in Excel. Only Power BI.

Comment: It could be a bug if only Power BI does it that way. Have you tried restarting your computer and Power BI Desktop just to be thorough?

Comment: I marked this as the answer because I think the "hidden" level is somehow related to the "Sort By Column" attribute in Analysis Services. At one point I was getting the classic error that "at least one value in Level2 has multiple distinct values in [sort column]" which I believed I had worked-around, but I think there's still an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm chocking this up to a bug (in the AAS connector to Cosmos (Beta), or some corruption in the model as a result of it) per my updated question. Although I can't pinpoint the issue, I've verified that manually recreating the model from scratch using the latest (non-Beta) connector this behavior is no longer reproducible.